# How do I change the maximum resolution of my computer for multiple monitors?

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, monitor

I am trying to enable three monitors for my setup in Ubuntu 12.10. My card is a Raedon 5700 HD series. When I try to extend my display to any additional monitors, I get the following error:

```
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3200, 900), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1600, 1600)
```

All I should have to do is increase my maximum resolution to a larger value. For example, let's say that I had three monitors with 1600x900 resolution. I would need to change it to 4800x900 (correct me if I'm wrong). How would I go about doing this?

This is my xorg.conf file. I'm not sure if I'll need to edit this. I don't even know where these values are stored. I'm not very good with Linux, so please try to explain in as simple terms as possible.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection
```